# Django: href {% url %} issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

Why does

```
<a href="{% url 'answers.views.display_answers' Question.id %}">View answers</a>
```

in my template translate to this interpretation by Django:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/%7B%%20url%20'answers.views.display_answers'%20Question.id
```

which of course leads to an url mismatch error.

Seems like its reading in my '{' in ASCII form. Can anyone enlighten me as to why it is so?

EDIT:

This was how i rendered the template--

```
return render(request, 'display_questions.html', context)
```

and the template contains the href. My display answer view redirects to another view as such:

```
def display_answers(request, q_id): 
        q = get_object_or_404(Question, id=q_id) 
        ans_list = Answer.objects.filter(question=q) 
        context = {'question': q, 'ans_list': ans_list} 
        return redirect('view_answers.html', context)
```

Error:

The current URL, questions/{% url 'answers.views.display_answers' Question.id, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Are you actually rendering that template? Looks like it's just being returned to the browser unparsed.

Comment: Yea I did render this template like so:
 return render(request, 'display_questions.html', context)
and the template contains the href.

My display answer view then attempts to redirect to another view as such:
def display_answers(request, q_id):
 q = get_object_or_404(Question, id=q_id)
 ans_list = Answer.objects.filter(question=q)
 context = {'question': q, 'ans_list': ans_list}
 return redirect('view_answers.html', context)

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't use a template as the argument to `redirect`. Please *edit the question* and add your **actual** code.

Comment: Oh i didn't know i can't use the template as the argument to redirect. thank you for pointing that out. 
But even so, the display_question.html was rendered, not redirected but it could not process the href tag.

Comment: If you take away the single quotes in the {% url ... %}, does it work?

Comment: why is Question not question in the template?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. If not - your `urls.py` seems to be wrong. Please post it.

```
<a href="{% url answers.views.display_answers question.id %}">View answers</a>
```

**Edit**
Here's a better version of your view.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404

def display_answers(request, q_id): 
    q = get_object_or_404(Question, id=q_id) 
    ans_list = Answer.objects.filter(question=q) 
    context = {'question': q, 'ans_list': ans_list} 
    return render_to_response('view_answers.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Didn't mean to downvote you, but now it's locked in. Can you edit your post insignificantly so it will allow me to change my vote?

Comment: it doesn't matter - i'm not that "omg i need more points here!!1" guys :) but thx for being honest

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `redirect` in the view. You should be using `render` or `render_to_response` unless you actually want to redirect the browser. (Observe using Fiddler, Firebug, or Chrome's developer tools and you'll see that it is redirecting.)

The reason this is not as obvious of a problem is because `redirect` may take a URL as its first argument. `'view_answers.html'` is being interpreted as a relative URL, which may or may not map to a URL in your URLconf. If it does map to a URL, then you get a false positive result that everything appears to be working, but if your web server handles that link instead of Django, then it may just send the template page back in plain text. The solution is, as I said, either `render` or `render_to_response` for rendering a page, or `redirect` with the name of a view or the special name of a URL pattern to redirect to a different view.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your redirect in your `display_answers` view to use the name of the view, instead of the name of your template (`view_answers.html`) and don't pass it the context ([`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) doesn't take the context as a parameter):

```
return redirect('your_view_answers_view')
```

Comment: doesn't `redirect` need the `reverse` for named views? like `return redirect(reverse('your_view_answers_view'))`?